# Google TTS API returns broken link

Tags: url, mp3, google-api, text-to-speech

This solution works fine in IE returning an MP3 file but not Chrome or FF

```
<div class="ttslink" onclick='
$("#please").text("please be patient!").css("color","green").fadeIn(300).delay(1400).fadeOut(300);
var kor = encodeURI($("#base").text());
window.open("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ko&q="+kor,"mywindow","location=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,width=0,height=0");'>
```

Comment: and btw in FF it plays a sound file but it always just says "unknown alphabet" in korean, perhaps a character encoding problem?